# MOSFET for Vgs(on)

Tags: mosfet, component-selection

How can i get the Vgs(on) if the datasheet like the [VN10LM](http://njsemi.com/datasheets/VN0610LL%20-%20VN10LM.pdf) don't have that specification. I only can se the values of Vgs(th) and Id(on), but I still mess the Vgs(on) to resolve the ecuation K = Id(on) / (Vgs(on) - Vgs(th))^2, that is part of Id = k (Vgs - Vgs(th))^2. I have all the values, the only one that i dont have is Vgs(on).

Comment: Look at the graphs. *On* is different things in different situations.

Comment: @greybeard There are no graphs in the linked datasheet.

Comment: (Where possible, go to the manufacturer for specifications. Didn't find one for TEMIC's VN10LM.) There's [RS's](https://docs.rs-online.com/fab6/0900766b80026c86.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

It is given in the datasheet. It's a test condition for measuring \$r_{ds}({\rm on})\$ and \$I_d({\rm on})\$:
[image]